# How to run more than one query in 1 get call nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest

```
app.get('/projects/:company_id', function(req, res){
    var company_id = req.params.company_id;

    //query1
    db.projects.count({"company_id": company_id },function(err, doc){   
        res.json(doc);
    });
    //query2
    db.projects.find({"company_id": company_id },function(err, doc){    
        res.json(return_data);
    });
});
```

Basically I want these two queries to run in parallel and then send the output to front end. I am not sure how to achieve that, guys help!.
Also is there an easy way to separate these two results in front end. I am using angular js.

Comment: check the response.

Comment: What is `return_data`?

Comment: @noisypixy i think he means the combined data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait both queries are finished.

Of course you need promises inside it, so we wrap each of the two function of yours in a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which is fulfilled when the callback is called.

If one of the two queries fail, then also `Promise.all()` fails and we send back to the client the error.

To separate data in the reply I split the data in two fields, `count` and `find`. In this way you can read them easily from angularjs and use them as you wish

```
app.get('/projects/:company_id', function(req, res){
    var company_id = req.params.company_id;

    Promise.all(
      new Promise(resolve, reject) {
        db.projects.count({"company_id": company_id },function(err, doc){   
          if (err) return reject(err);
          resolve(doc);
        });
      },
      new Promise(resolve, reject) {
        db.projects.find({"company_id": company_id },function(err, doc){   
          if (err) return reject(err);
          resolve(doc);
        });
      }
    )
    .then(data) {
      res.json({
        "count": data[0],
        "find": data[1]
      });
    }
    .catch(error) {
      res.json({
        "error": error
      });
    }
});
```

If you can't use Promises 'cause you're using node.js 0.10.x, you can do something like this:

```
app.get('/projects/:company_id', function(req, res){
    var company_id = req.params.company_id;
    var reply = {
      find: -1,
      count: -1
    }
    var errorSent = false;

    function sendErr(e) {
      if (errorSent) return; // Do not send twice a reply
      res.json({"error": e});
      errorSent = 1;
    }

    function sendWhenReady() {
      if (reply.count !== -1 && reply.find !== -1) res.send(reply);
    }


    //query1
    db.projects.count({"company_id": company_id },function(err, doc){
        if (err) return sendError(err);
        reply.count = doc;   
        sendWhenReady();
    });
    //query2
    db.projects.find({"company_id": company_id },function(err, doc){ 
        if (err) return sendError(err);   
        reply.find = doc;   
        sendWhenReady();
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for you reply, but in the first solution which you gave using promise, is throwing error, the second solution is working

Answer (score 0):

You could run them side by side and send the data after both run. Check [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async) which is one of many libraries to do such operations easily.

```
var async = require("async");
async.parallel({
    one: function(callback) {
        db.projects.count({"company_id": company_id },function(err, doc){   
            callback(null, doc)
        });
    },
    two: function(callback) {
        db.projects.find({"company_id": company_id },function(err, doc){    
            callback(null, doc);
        });
    }
}, function(err, results) {
    var payload = {
        count : results.one,
        data: results.two
    }
    res.json(payload);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without any additional library, you could do something similar to this:

```
app.get('/projects/:company_id', function(req, res) {
  // Create an object resembling your final response,
  // but replace the values with a promise.
  var futureData = {
    count: new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      db.projects.count({'company_id': company_id}, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        return resolve(doc);
      });
    }),
    results: new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      db.projects.find({'company_id': company_id}, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        return resolve(doc);
      });
    }),
  };

  var keys = Object.keys(futureData);

  // Wait until all promises are resolved.
  Promise.all(
    keys.map(key => futureData[key])
  )
    // Get the response object.
    .then(function(values) {
      // Build an object from the results of the promises,
      // using the same key as in `futureData`.
      return values.reduce(function(data, value, i) {
        var key = keys[i];
        data[key] = value;
        return data;
      }, {});
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      // Send final data.
      res.json(data);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      // TODO: Handle error.
    });
});
```